# How does linux kernel separate userspace stacks of multiple threads in the same thread group?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-management, process, linux-kernel

As I understand, a new Light Weight Process(thread) is created by calling `clone()` with the `CLONE_VM` flag set, which means `mm_struct`, hence the list of `vm_area_struct` are all shared across threads, and even the Page Table is shared, but then how does kernel keep track of each individual thread's user stack?

For a normal `clone()` without `CLONE_VM`, the Page Table will be duplicated so that Copy On Write kicks in if the child or parent process modifies any shared page, including the stack area. Essentially COW is just a trick on top of the fact that the new process should/will have a completely *independent* memory space going forward, it just shares pages with its parent when possible for multiple efficiency-related reasons. Clearly when `CLONE_VM` is set this mechanism does not apply anymore.

The only way I can think of is that there are multiple `vm_area_struct` in `mm_struct` that are basically each thread's stack space, although all threads can 'see' each other's stack, they only use their own. But even if this is true:

1. which function is responsible for allocating a new stack space after cloning? Some library function that wraps around `clone()` does this?
2. `mm_struct`'s `start_stack` field has to choose one out of multiple threads, and if by default it is unchanged, it will point to the thread group leader's stack?

Not sure if my understanding above is correct, help appreciated.

Comment: 1. The `clone(2)` libc wrapper takes a `fn` function and a `child_stack` argument, and switches to it in the child. Whoever is calling it has to allocate the stack. The actual `clone()` syscall has a completely different signature -- look towards the end of the `clone(2)` manpage. When using `pthread_create()` & such it's the thread library which takes care of allocating and managing the memory for the stacks. 2. Exactly. You can see that by simply creating a couple of sleeping threads and looking in their `/proc/PID/task/TID/{stat,maps}`.

Comment: Notice that the memory for the stack is allocated _before_, not after cloning.

Comment: thanks. the code indeed lives in pthread layer.